# innerHTML in IE?

Tags: php, javascript, internet-explorer, innerhtml

I'm having trouble using innerHTML with my radio type button.

```
<table align="center">
 <div class='main'>
  <span id="js" class='info'>
   <label><input type="radio" name="js" value="0" size="<?php echo $row['size']; ?>" onclick="js(this.value, this.size);" /><img src="arrowup.png"/></label>
   <br />
   <label><input type="radio" name="js" value="1" size="<?php echo $row['size']; ?>" onclick="js(this.value, this.size);" /><img src="arrowdown.png"/></label>
  </span>
 </div>
</table>
```

My .js looks like this:

```
var xmlhttp;

function getVote(a,b) {
xmlhttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
if (xmlhttp==null)   {
  alert ("Browser does not support HTTP Request");
  return;
  }
var url="js.php";
url=url+"?js="+a;
url=url+"&id="+b;
url=url+"&sid="+Math.random();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged;
xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
xmlhttp.send(null);
}

function stateChanged() {

  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4) {
  document.getElementById("js").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
  }
}

function GetXmlHttpObject() {
var objXMLHttp=null;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)   {
  objXMLHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else if (window.ActiveXObject)   {
  objXMLHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
return objXMLHttp;
}
```

This doesn't work in IE only! Any help?

Comment: Have you checked whether `document.getElementById("js")` is finding an element at all?  It might not be a problem with innerHTML. I think getElementById could fail if you have invalid markup, which is hard to tell without you supplying a doctype and such (if there is one).  Also, getElementById should return a single element -- are you expecting it to return a collection containing the span with `id="js"` *and* the inputs with `name="js"`  Possibly your issue is due to having names and id's that are the same.

Comment: See here for an example of way name and id conflicts are problematic:
http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200802/beware_of_id_and_name_attribute_mixups_when_using_getelementbyid_in_internet_explorer/

Comment: @Andrew Moore: `size="<?php echo $row['size']; ?>"` has nothing to do with PHP?

Comment: @John Saunders: That's a very, very small piece of a large puzzle. And I think that piece has been misplaced and isn't needed to solve this particular puzzle.

Comment: @Andrew: it may not be needed, but it should be a tag. Still, I won't put it back if you take it off again.

Comment: For starters, your HTML is invalid.  If you're going to use a table, you need to use `tr` and `td`, otherwise, there's really no point

Comment: Use jQuery or some other library for AJAX. Writing it Yourselt isn't worth it.

Answer (score 2):

firstly, pretty sure a DIV directly inside a TABLE is illegal markup.

don't use illegal markup. browsers will respond differently to it (i've recently had Opera ignore some illegal stuff with IE trying to render it).

tho IE usually deserves it, firstly get the markup correct and then see how IE does. it may be that it has failed to render the DOM how you expect.

(FWIW there is an innerHTML rendering problem i've run up against with IE, http://support.microsoft.com/kb/276228/, but for the SELECT element so i don't think it applies here).

Answer (score 1):

The issue was indeed innerHTML on table tag. IE doesn't support innerHTML wrapped around a table tag nor they intend to resolve this issue in their future releases.

The workaround is to either use DOM methods or the easiest way: wrap your table around a div.

So I ended up with:

```
<div id="js" align="center"><table>
        <span class='main'>
            <a onClick="getVote(this.value, this.size);" type="radio" value="0" size="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" /><img src="arrowup.png"/></a>
            <br /><a onClick="getVote(this.value, this.size);" type="radio" value="1" size="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" /><img src="arrowdown.png"/></a>
            </span>
</table></div>
```

There's another IE bug that screws up the label if they're set to be image. Just a heads up! I know you won't be surprised when I say IE sucks!

Comment: innerHTML doesn't wrap anything... IE doesn't like partially re-parsing the insides of a table, so wrap one or more tables with a div and use the div.innerHTML. Can't blame IE if you won't toss your own tag salad: <table><span>... isn't valid HTML.

Comment: Yeah, but if it isn't valid HTML then I wonder why would it work on all other browsers ...

Comment: For more info on this issue: http://www.ericvasilik.com/2006/07/code-karma.html

Eric is the inventor of innerHTML ... hope it helps.

Comment: "Yeah, but if it isn't valid HTML then I wonder why would it work on all other browsers " Because of people like *you*, who naively support non-standard code. Sorry but this is simply the truth, breaking standards is the root of all evil, _especially_ on the web. One browser with big market share starts doing its own thing, then other browsers copy it, or else they lose market share.

Comment: What is annoying is that when it **is** valid HTML and you add it and it works in all browsers except IE.  HTML5 makes innerHTML part of the spec to apply to all elements that can contain HTML. Hopefully this means IE9 (due out ~April 12, 2011) will have innerHTML fixed! ;-)

Comment: not that this helps anything, but I frickn' hate IE.  Thanks for the solution

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a little late but here is how to fix this issue with jQuery:

```
$("#tableName").html(DataToWrite);
```