# Alternative to innerHTML for ie (Internet Explorer

Tags: php, internet-explorer, select, innerhtml, xajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [innerHTML working in FF but not in IE!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801960/innerhtml-working-in-ff-but-not-in-ie)
>   [innerHTML in IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305038/innerhtml-in-ie)

I am using innerHTML in an XAJAX registered function to dynamically build a SELECT tag.
The function is working correctly in FIREFOX, CHROME, and SAFARI, but it does not work in IE. Is there an alternative to using innerHTML to make this work in IE? 
Here is a listing of the function:

```
function getProducts($category_sname)
 {
    global $current_item_id;
    /*** a new xajax response object ***/
    $objResponse=new xajaxResponse();
    $objResponse->script("clearOption('item_identification');");

    $category_name = substr($category_sname,1,39);
                $cat_list = Jelly::select('catmst')
                        ->select('category_identification','name')
                        ->and_where('name','=',$category_name)
                        ->deleteflag()
                        ->execute();

                foreach ($cat_list as $catl)
                {
                        $category_id = $catl->category_identification;
                }
    /*** get the item_identification data ***/
    $OL=array();
    $OL=getProductData($category_id);

    /*** set first value ***/
    $ret = '<option value="">Select One</option>';
    foreach ($OL as $value => $text)
    {
        /*** the product dropdown options ***/
    $ret .= '<option value="'.$value.'">'.$text.'</option>';
    }
    /*** assign the options to the item_identification div ***/
    $objResponse->assign('item_identification', 'innerHTML', $ret);
    return $objResponse;
 }
```

Comment: Have you searched SO for other questions that resolve your issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305038/innerhtml-in-ie?rq=1 | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801960/innerhtml-working-in-ff-but-not-in-ie?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

More portable way of dealing with `<select>` element in DOM model is described in http://support.microsoft.com/kb/276228